# Нужна ли запятая? Обособленное обстоятельство?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, обстоятельство

Из-за сопротивления [,] напряжение уменьшается по мере удаления от места, где ток попадает в землю.

Answer (score 2):

***Из-за сопротивления** напряжение уменьшается по мере удаления от места, где ток попадает в землю.*

Обстоятельственные обороты обособляются факультативно, с учетом влияния различных факторов. См.: [ОБСТОЯТЕЛЬСТВА, ВЫРАЖЕННЫЕ СУЩЕСТВИТЕЛЬНЫМИ](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=114#pp114) (Розенталь).

Нераспространенная падежная форма в начале предложения практически **не обособляется**, особенно в деловых или технических текстах.

Обстоятельственный оборот относится ко всему предложению и произносится с небольшой паузой, но эта пауза **не является грамматической** и не обозначается запятой.

Примечание

Содержание первой части  неясно воспринимается на слух. Желательно как-то распространить оборот (из-за сопротивления чего, из-за какого сопротивления), тогда он будет более удобен для произношения и понимания.

Comment: Получается, что перед вторым `**` пробел нельзя ставить.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь минимальная распространённость оборота  (ср. "из-за этого") в начале предложения, поэтому обособления (оно в общем случае предложных сочетаний с существительным факультативно, http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=114#pp114) не требуется.